# Can Roslyn parse my "user-defined" syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Can I have some user-defined syntax in the text and parse it using Roslyn(maybe a customized lexcial/syntax analyzer)? If yes, which document/namespace should I look into?

The text I want to parse is just an single "expression", not a whole program, like:

```
A.B + Foo(Bar) and !Baz
```

Here I want to "tell" the lexical analyzer that `+` `!` `and` `!` are operators and `Foo(Bar)` is a function call. Is there something like a `LexicalWalker` that I can define my logics and then Roslyn can parse the text into correct tokens so that I can continue to analyze the tokens?

Comment: While I have seen Roslyn parse almost anything, it could come out quite weird. Some of my experiments: https://gist.github.com/leppie/5081390

Comment: @leppie: Interesting... how can Roslyn "guess" `MyFor` is a method? By the left parenthesis following? A bit reckless.

Comment: I agree. That is why I never explored any further ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) quite suitable for my requirement.

Comment: Can you expand on this? What exactly did you do using Irony?